# Appending to a WaveStream

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to stream sound using Naudio. The thing I am having trouble with is that I can't write to a WaveStream. I tried making a queue of smaller WaveStream but I don't think this is not the way to go. How can I stream an mp3 file, or wave file over the network and start playing it even if it is not completely transferred?

Comment: Wrong library to implement streaming, I think.

Comment: which library would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `BufferedWaveProvider`, it can be used as an input to WaveOut and allows you to queue up buffers for playback. You would however need to decode the MP3 file frame by frame yourself using the MP3Frame class, as the MP3FileReader expects to be able to reposition to the end.